# How do I scroll all the contents of my custom QGraphicsWidgets?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicswidget

I have a custom QGraphicsWidget called "TestContentArea" which is added to a QGraphicsScene.  In my custom QGraphicsWidget, I am adding a number of children QGraphicsWidgets added to its layout.  The problem I have is the contents of custom QGraphicsWidget extends beyond the area the user can scroll.  Attached below is a minimum example that shows this.  Only 11 rectangles are visible out of a 100.  How can I scroll all 100 children widgets in this example?

MainWindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>

#include "TestContentArea.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    //Constructor
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    //Deconstructor
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    //Private members
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QGraphicsScene * m_scene;
    QGraphicsView * m_view;
    TestContentArea * m_testContentArea;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H

MainWindow.cpp:

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    m_scene = new QGraphicsScene(0, 0, 880, 630, this);

    m_view = new QGraphicsView(m_scene, this);
    m_view->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);

    m_testContentArea = new TestContentArea();
    m_scene->addItem(m_testContentArea);

    setCentralWidget(m_view);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

TestContentArea.h:

#ifndef TESTCONTENTAREA_H
#define TESTCONTENTAREA_H

#include <QGraphicsWidget>
#include <QGraphicsLinearLayout>


class TestContentArea: public QGraphicsWidget
{
public:
    //Constructor
    TestContentArea(QGraphicsWidget* parent = nullptr);

private:
    //Private members
    QGraphicsLinearLayout * m_layout;

};

#endif // TESTCONTENTAREA_H


TestContentArea.cpp:

#include "TestContentArea.h"

#include <QGraphicsLinearLayout>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include "RectangleWidget.h"

TestContentArea::TestContentArea(QGraphicsWidget* parent)
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);

    setAcceptHoverEvents(true);

    m_layout = new QGraphicsLinearLayout(Qt::Vertical, this);
    m_layout->setContentsMargins(30, 30, 0, 0);

    for(int i= 0; i< 100; i++)
    {
        RectangleWidget* rect = new RectangleWidget(this);
        m_layout->addItem(rect);

    }

    setLayout(m_layout);

}

RectangleWidget.h:

#ifndef Rectangle_H
#define Rectangle_H

#include <QGraphicsWidget>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QGraphicsLinearLayout>
#include <QGraphicsProxyWidget>
#include <QPushButton>

class RectangleWidget: public QGraphicsWidget
{
public:
    RectangleWidget(QGraphicsWidget* parent = nullptr);

    // Overriding functions
    QRectF boundingRect() const override;
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget = nullptr) override;

private:
    //Private member variables
    QGraphicsLinearLayout * m_layout;
    QPushButton * m_button;


};

#endif // Rectangle_H

RectangleWidget.cpp:

#include "RectangleWidget.h"
#include <QPainter>

RectangleWidget::RectangleWidget(QGraphicsWidget *parent)
{

}

void RectangleWidget::paint(QPainter *painter,
    const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget /*= 0*/)
{
    Q_UNUSED(widget);
    Q_UNUSED(option);

    //Draw border
    painter->drawRoundedRect(boundingRect(), 0.0, 0.0);
}

QRectF RectangleWidget::boundingRect() const
{

    return QRectF(QPointF(0,0), geometry().size());
}
```

[image: Only 11 rectangles visible out of 100]

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: How about [QScrollArea](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html)?

Comment: @eyllanesc I went ahead and put together a minimal example.  In this example only 11 children widgets are displayed (can't scroll any further).  I hope this provides you enough information.  Thanks.

Comment: what is `ButtonWidget`?

Comment: your code is clearly not a [mcve], I have tried to patch what is missing and I do not see any problem since QGraphicsView has vertical and horizontal scrollbar, it could show an image of the problem and improve the code it shows.

Comment: @eyllanesc  ButtonWidget is intended to be RectangleWidget.  I missed that in scaling down my code to a minimal example.  If you look at the code you should be able to scroll and see 100 rectangle widgets nested inside the TestContentArea, but also only 11 is visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused because you are defining a very small `sceneRect` compared to what it should be, and that is that the `QScrollBar` take as references the `SceneRect` to establish its range. So the solution is simple, do not set any `sceneRect` so that Qt calculates it by itself, for it changes:

```
m_scene = new QGraphicsScene(0, 0, 880, 630, this);
```

to:

```
m_scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
```

Comment: I originally added that code to set the scene to the same exact dimensions of the MainWindow.  I had no idea that it would restrict the entire area.  Thank you very much for your answer!